# Effecient Way to Access an Element of a PyTorch Tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to extract only the first element of a very large pytorch tensor. I've seen posts talking about options like `my_tensor.numpy()[0]` or `my_tensor.detach().numpy()[0]` if I'm using requires_grad. This seems really inefficient just to access one element, especially if my tensor is big. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Any reason you can't do `my_tensor[0].item()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1d tensor, you can access the first element with :

```
my_tensor[0].item()
```

If your tensor is higher dimensional, you will need to index it like:

```
my_3dtensor[0,0,0].item()
```